# What is the three-parameter family of time translation Killing field in Minkowski spacetime?

Tags: general-relativity, special-relativity, differential-geometry

In section 5.1 of Wald's *Quantum Field Theory in Curved Spacetime and Black Hole Thermodynamics*, there are two paragraphs before the discussion of Unruh effect as follows.

> Let us reconsider the construction of quantum field theory in Minkowski spacetime from the perspective of the general prescription for constructing quantum field theory in an arbitrary, globally hyperbolic, stationary spacetime (see section 4.3). Let ξ^a denote an "ordinary time translation" Killing field, corresponding to the "time direction" of some global family of inertial observers. Then eq. (4.3.2) holds, so if m > 0 we may apply the stationary quantization prescription of section 4.3. (If m = 0 this construction also works for spacetime dimension greater than two; however, infrared divergences occur when one attempts to apply this construction to two-dimensional Minkowski spacetime.) The result of applying this prescription, of course, is precisely the standard quantum field theory that we previously constructed in section 3.2.

> In fact, **Minkowski spacetime possesses a three-parameter family of "ordinary time translations", corresponding to the different possible choices of "time direction" for global families of inertial observers**. Hence, one could repeat the above construction making a different choice of time translation Killing field. However, it is not difficult to show that the use of a different time translation Killing field gives rise to precisely the same μ, and thus the quantum field construction actually does not depend upon the choice of ξ^a (see Chmielowski (1994) for a proof of a generalization of this result). This result may be interpreted as saying that different global families of inertial observers will agree upon the "particle content" of any state of the field.

Question: What is the **three-parameter family of "ordinary time translations" (Killing field)**?

Comment: He's just saying that the space of normalized timelike vectors is 3-dimensional (4-vector minus 1 normalization constraint).

Comment: @PeterKravchuk: that looks like an answer to me!

Answer (score 1):

Pick a reference frame in Minkowski spacetime. Consider the observer at rest in the origin. This observer's four-velocity defines an ordinary time-translation Killing field. However, if you use a Lorentz boost to change reference frames you can find a new observer at rest in the new origin. This observer's four-velocity also defines an ordinary time-translation Killing field. Notice you can do this construction how many times you want. The complete family of time-translation Killing fields can be obtained by varying the three parameters governing the possible boosts: the velocities along each of the coordinate axis $(v_x,v_y,v_z)$. Hence, using these three parameters, you can get the full family of ordinary time-translation Killing fields.

The word "ordinary" refers to the fact that the Killing field is the four-velocity of some inertial observer.